# Get data from database with respect to all the values in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a drop down that has multiple values 1,2,3 with their respective name fields.
I need to get data from the database with respect to the all the values in the Drop down list.
For example if the drop down list has 3 different values the other drop down should have all the corresponding values of the values present in the first drop down..Like 1,2,3 ..if the values of the first drop down increases or decreases ..the 2nd drop down should match with the data accordingly. 
Thank you.

```
SELECT Player_Detail.Player_Serno              
FROM  Player_Detail INNER JOIN
               Team_Detail ON Player_Detail.Club = Team_Detail.Serno
WHERE (Player_Detail.Club = @Team1 OR
               Player_Detail.Club = @Team2) AND (Player_Detail.First_Name)
ORDER BY Team_Detail.Team_Name
```

> ```
>  <SelectParameters>
>  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Teams_Drop" Name="Team1" 
>  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
>  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Teams_Drop" Name="Team2" 
>  PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
>  </SelectParameters>
> ```

I have tried this and It still shows single value.

Comment: What is your question precisely and what have you tried?

Comment: Close vote retracted. Please remember to always include any attempted solutions and relevant code when asking for code. On topic: Have you tried simply binding the second dropdown list to the same datasource as the first?

Comment: enable the postback property to true..then dont use this sort of binding..Do everything from code behind itself.It will be helpful when changing dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand, you have two dropdowns, Lets say dropdown1, dropdown2.
You just need bind data dropdown2 as per selected value indropdown1.

You can fetch list of data for dropdown2, in dropdown1's SelectedIndexChange Event.

[This explains much better](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response..But y issue is i have a bunch of values in 1..for example 1,2,3 ..i want the second drop down to bind having all the values of 1,2,and 3 and if obviously synchronize when ever values change in the 1st dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is your question is not so clear ... as far i understand you want to list all the data associated with values in drop down

For this you have to select all data using OR

Comment: but how do i do that..the code i have pasted is the "or" that i am using...now the issue is what do i relate the values tothe other dropdown..It shows only the first value ..but i need all the data related to all the date related to the vales